# Create Windows DNS PTR records for existing A records using Powershell

Tags: powershell, dns

Anyone know an easy way to force PTR record generation for existing A records that currently do not have them?

I have a couple of scenarios where this would be beneficial to me.

1. Members of my team have created records over time using the DNS MMC snap-in, but forgot to check the "Update PTR record" option, and
2. I have *many* reverse lookup zones for individual subnets that I'm trying to collapse into an also existing parent reverse zone... e.g. 1.192.10.in-addr.arpa -> 192.10.in-addr.arpa.

My thought process was to simply run through existing A records and run a pre-built DNS cmdlet with some sort of **-updatePTR** type flag, similar as can be done in the MMC snapin, but I guess nothing like that exists in Powershell.

The Add-DNSServerResourceRecord cmdlet has the -CreatePTR parameter, which sounds ideal, but that seems to only be supported when creating *new* records.

Is my only option to manually create the PTR records using Add-DNSServerResourceRecortPTR, or something similar, or perhaps even deleting the A record entirely and recreating with -CreatePTR?

I can do the former by following something similar to this:
https://gist.github.com/msoler8785/498332c622f93ace02b5d05e47845001, but I have hundreds of these zones I'm trying to cleanup from years of acquisitions, etc., which would make the code a lot more complex by requiring me to determine the correct Reverse zones based on the IP addresses, whereas that code uses a static zone.

Anyway, hoping I'm just missing something, or someone else has already figured this out.

**::EDIT::**

I found this which uses WMI/Powershell to do the first method, but I imagine this could easily converted to the native cmdlets.

https://serverfault.com/questions/163612/create-ptr-records-from-existing-a-records-windows-dns

Again, hoping someone has already figured this out.

Comment: The additional info on your first link appears to have all the pieces you need. Please give it a shot and if you hit a road block then come back and share your code and what’s happening/not happening.